# Should we use "must", "should", or "have to" when we are talking about the only remaiining possibility?

Tags: word-choice

> There are only these two possibilities A and B. It was proved that it
>   is not A. So it ... be B.

In the above sorts of sentences, what should be used for the blank: "must", "should" or "have to"?

I found out in my research that "must" and "have to" is for more strong and inevitable obligations such as rules. So, it *must* be either "must" or "have to"! But I anyway like to know your views about the word choice in my sentence.

Comment: It must be B. As a modal auxiliary Must is commonly used to express a logical possibility.

Comment: All modals have two kinds of meaning. One, called Deontic, has to do with social rules, obligations, and permissions: _She must be home by midnight or she'll be grounded_. The other kind, called Epistemic, has to do with logical or probabilistic statements, not obligations: _She must be home by now; it's past 2400_.

Comment: Both "must" and "has to" are both correct and have the same meaning. Their function is using logic or deduction to determine what's true.

Answer (score 1):

I have read on a couple of different sites (https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/modals-1 and https://www.gymglish.com/en/english-grammar/must-vs-have-to that *has to* would be the correct term to use in this example.

According to these resources, *must* is used when the obligation is coming from the speaker, and *have to* is used when the source of the obligation is someone or something other than the speaker (i.e., another person or a law/rule).

In the example you have used, the obligation is a result of a logical rule, and this is why the sentence should read, "So it has to be B."

However, this answer is based on the information given on a couple of sites that happened to rank high on a google search for "must vs. have to," and so this could be wrong; hopefully, someone will let us know if so.

Comment: See @JohnLawler's comment on the question.There are two meanings/uses of *must*, and one of them *does* apply here, just as much as *has to* applies here. In this context, *must* means that it is *necessarily* so.

Comment: I'd agree that there are slightly different distributions for deontic 'must' and 'have to'. 'Must' is less hedged. You wouldn't hear 'You have to obey!' from a Dalek. // But this example uses epistemic 'must' and 'have to'. I'd say they're closely synonymous here.

Answer (score 1):

"Should" makes it sound like you're doubting yourself. It sounds as if you feel your logic isn't sound.

"Must" or "has to" are both right.